# Http POST XML data to the Server from an Angular material textarea

Tags: angular, angular-material, http-post

I set up an Server that accepts XML inputs. 
I want to send a XML messages from the angular frontend. I'm very new with angular!

I created a textarea using angular material, where I write the [xml input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HafGf.png). 
Here is the XML I want to send:

```
<SendMessage>
    <Message Name="Test1" Message="Test2" Version="01.00"/>
</SendMessage>
```

I updated the **MessageService** to add the **headers**, and I manually wrote some example xml just to see if it will work with this code:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

  private url: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/bg/sendMessage';
  }

  createMessage() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Accept': 'application/xml',
        'Response-Type': 'text'
      })
    };
    const postedData = `
      <SendMessage>
         <Message Name="Test1" Message="Test2" Version="01.00"/>
      </SendMessage>`;
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url, postedData, httpOptions).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log('The result is:', result);
      },
      error => console.log('There was an error', error)
    );
  }
}
```

Then I updated the **MessageComponent** too:

```
export class MessagesComponent {

  constructor(public messageService: MessageService) {
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    this.messageService.createMessage();
  }
}
```

And here is my **Message.html** file, where I just added a click event for the button. When I click on the button, I should be able to send the xml:

```
    <mat-card>
  <form  >
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field >
        <textarea  matInput placeholder="Xml Message"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button  mat-raised-button (click)="onFormSubmit()">Send Message</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Unfortunately I get an the error **"There was an error"** and

```
POST http://localhost:8080/bg/sendMessage net::ERR_FAILED
```

When I check the Network in the browser, there is no response and sendMessage failed.

Then I checked the backend, and saw that it threw an error while the frontend was sending the request.

The error in the backend is: **Content type 'text/plain' not supported**

For the *Content-Type* I used *application/xml* I don't understand where the problem can be!

Any suggestion of what I could improve to at least get a response?

*P.S. I tested the backend with Postman and everything works correctly.*

Comment: bro you have to send in Header, 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'

Comment: @kashif thank you for the suggestion, I did what you said. Unfortunately, I got an error and it didn't work. I tried to solve the error but without success. I updated the question again with the improvements.